# Issue working with UITableView prototype cell in StoryBoard when using Content Offset in viewDidLoad()

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UIViewController` that contains a `UITableView` and a `UISearchBar`.  The two controls are at the same level in the view hierarchy.

The Search Bar covers the first cell of the Table View, so in `viewDidLoad()` I adjust the Content Inset of the Table View by Y = 64 (20 for the status bar + 44 for the Search Bar).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Everything works fine at runtime.

The problem is when I try to work with the prototype cell at design time it is covered by the Search Bar as shown below:

[image]

What is the proper approach here?

Comment: Don't ever hardcode heights like this. What about the iPhone X and the in-call status bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this entirely in the storyboard.

1. Remove the constraint `Table View.top = top`
2. Add a new constraint that connects the top of the table view to the bottom of the search bar

You'll likely need to adjust the origin and height of the tableview, since its new `origin.y` will be the search bar's `origin.y + size.height`

And yes - hard coding magic numbers that correspond to things in your storyboard is a bad idea.